# javafx webengine url interception

Tags: java, javafx-webengine

I'm working with this Web Browser:

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/SimpleSwingBrowser.java.htm

and I'm having having a path problems, so I need to intercept URL requests. If anyone can help?

Comment: Be clear when asking question

Comment: I need to intercept URL's. Nothing more. There is no ambiguity there.